# Windows Container (Nano Server) with ASP.NET Core

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I'm trying to make an Windows Nano Server container that runs an ASP.NET Core app.
 I'm building it on Windows Server 2016.  I can make it work, but there is one odd problem.

The only way I can make it work is to build the image, run the container, *then* start an interactive Powershell session and use `Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:5000`.  Once I do that from *inside* the container, the app is visible from other servers (I can't browse the container locally from the Win2016 Server due to a known NAT bug.)

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk-nanoserver
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY /ContainerPOC/ .
RUN dotnet restore --runtime win10-x64 .

RUN dotnet build --framework netcoreapp1.1 --runtime win10-x64 .

EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:5000
CMD dotnet run --framework netcoreapp1.1
```

Any idea why this won't "just work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
λ  cat .\Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-preview1-sdk-nanoserver

WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet new mvc
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:5000
CMD dotnet run

C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-preview1-sdk-nanoserver
 ---> d92a15cb72c5
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7405c251e8ee
Step 3/7 : RUN dotnet new mvc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a13bf888f48a
Step 4/7 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f760754eaf62
Step 5/7 : RUN dotnet build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d661f94ef39
Step 6/7 : ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a912538a46a9
Step 7/7 : CMD dotnet run
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0b3712d69dae
Successfully built 0b3712d69dae
Successfully tagged test:latest
C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  docker run --name test -d -p 5000:5000 test^C
C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  docker rm -f test
test
C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  docker build -t test .^C
C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  docker run --name test -d -p 5000:5000 test
73dfc9706edb9d7956d0bc43113994066baad0f07db29b7a81f60a11e14d9e3a
C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  docker inspect --format "{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress}}" 73
172.17.59.102
C:\code\repros\dotnet-sample
λ  iwr -UseBasicParsing http://172.17.59.102:5000/


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
...
```

### Linux sample below

```
cat .\Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk

WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet new mvc
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:5000
CMD dotnet run
```

`docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
 ---> aeb44045bdf4
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 40d8474d3ff1
Step 3/7 : RUN dotnet new mvc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8447728b31dc
Step 4/7 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 81bbf373ae60
Step 5/7 : RUN dotnet build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95a83c304b53
Step 6/7 : ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9a265a927356
Step 7/7 : CMD dotnet run
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a962d986f3a6
Successfully built a962d986f3a6
Successfully tagged test:latest`

`docker run --name test -d -p 5000:5000 test
61ff30bc7488a0390af26a7a881fb4704d092ec89c49030d1935176b94e92a20`

```
docker inspect --format "{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress}}" 61ff
172.17.52.83
iwr -UseBasicParsing http://172.17.52.83:5000/


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

Comment: That is a linux-based container.  I'm trying to build a Nano Server container.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - It also works based on Windows for me, updated the sample.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes